# WPBakery Page builder stretch image full width

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

Wondering if any can help with this issue I'm having. I've inherited a site that uses wpbakery page builder. The original developer used a LOT of php to build the pages, but I am trying to make it easier for the client to use by rebuilding some pages with wpbakery. In order to get the site to flow well visually, I want to incorporate some background images that were included. However, the images are only 1440 px in width and I want them o stretch across the full screen for whatever size the window is. If I set the row to Stretch row and content (no padding) and have the image in a Single Image add-on, it still only displays as 1440 px wide at the largest. Tried it as a background image to the row, and that goes full width, but it doesn't shrink to the screen size fully. (leaves some image outside the boundaries when the screen gets smaller than 1440 px) Tried to give a Single Image a class and tell the class in the Custom CSS editor to be width: 100%, but that didn't work either. Anyone have any ideas as to how to implement this?

Comment: So, since there haven't been any ideas thrown out there, I decided to move on and try Siteorigin Page Builder instead of WPBakery. And this worked out way better. Was not aware of the limitations of WPBakery compared to Siteorigin.